# How to create a plugin to block magento2 from sending order confirmation mail?

Tags: magento2, sales-order, order-email

Need to block magento from sending orderconfirmation mail through a module. Which is  the efficient method to do so ?

Comment: You need to create Observer for convenient way

Comment: How so ? I'm new to magento2

Comment: Hi @Mohanarengan you got the answer ?

Comment: I wanted to send certain order mail details to rabbitmq. Have created a observer for sales_order_placed_after to get details to send to rabbitmq but haven't disabled order mail programmatically with observer.

Answer (score 0):

You can do easily from admin panel. Order email setting, Set it to No :

```
 Admin -> Stores -> Configuration -> Sales -> Sales Email -> Order -> Enabled
```